# Different Taylor expansions of sum of ArcTan[x] + ArcTan[y]

Tags: series-expansion

We all know that

> tan^(-1) (x) + tan^(-1)(y) = tan^(-1)((x+y)/(1-x*y))

I have below code for the `Series of Arctan[]` . The `Series` for the left hand side and right hand side of above equality have different results which certainly should have same results. I want to know which one is true and what makes them different.

```
aa[t_] := t^2*a[2] + t^3*a[3] + t^4*a[4] + t^5*a[5] + t^6*a[6] + O[t]^7;

cc[t_] := c[0] + t*c[1] + t^2*c[2] + t^3*c[3] + t^4*c[4] + t^5*c[5] + t^6*c[6] + O[t]^7;

trial1[t_] := Series[ArcTan[(1 - cc[t])*Sqrt[k/aa[t]]] +ArcTan[cc[t]*Sqrt[k/aa[t]]], {t, 0, 3}]

trial2[t_] := Series[ArcTan[(Sqrt[k/aa[t]]/(1 - cc[t]*(1 - cc[t])*k/aa[t]))], {t,0, 3}]
```

where `x = (1-cc[t])*Sqrt[k/aa[t]]` and `y = cc[t]*Sqrt[k/aa[t]]`

Please give me any idea why they show different expansions. Thanks..

Comment: I will question the underlying assertion of equality. `In[115]:= 
ArcTan[x] + ArcTan[y] - ArcTan[((x + y)/(1 - x*y))] /. {x -> -1 - I, 
   y -> -1 + I} // N

Out[115]= -3.14159265359 + 0. I`

Comment: Thanks so much @DanielLichtblau . So the suggested results are different then ?

Comment: The expressions are not in general equal, and this means their `Series` expansions might also differ.

Comment: How they are not generally equal @DanielLichtblau ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I showed an explicit counterexample to the putative expression equality in my original comment.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau , what does `I` mean in `x` and `y` ?  Also, in the answer below, bill s show that they are equal !

Comment: (1) They are not equal. (2) You should look up in documentation what is meant by `I` in Mathematica.

Comment: So, @DanielLichtblau , you are saying if `x` and `y` are complex numbers `ArcTan [x] + ArcTan  [y]` is not equal to `ArcTan [(x+y)/(1-xy)]`

Comment: Correct, they are not always equal.Not even for all reals. Here is a counterexample: `In[23]:= ArcTan[x] + ArcTan[y] - 
   ArcTan[((x + y)/(1 - x*y))] /. {x -> -20, y -> -55} // N

Out[23]= -3.14159265359`. What we see is a jump discontinuity from a  branch cut.

Comment: Thanks very very much @DanielLichtblau , the difference is large indeed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simplify a little and get it working there... compare:

```
Series[ArcTan[x] + ArcTan[y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

with

```
Series[ArcTan[((x + y)/(1 - x*y))], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]}
```

both give the same answer. The complexity increases rapidly though. With your functions cc and aa, just the first term is ridiculously complicated.

```
Series[ArcTan[x] /. {x -> (1 - cc[t])*Sqrt[k/aa[t]]}, {t, 0, 3}]
```

When I try to FullSimplify it, it doesn't finish (within a few minutes). So they probably show different answers because they are computed differently. If you wanted to check, you could plug in numbers and verify that they are equal in those special cases.

Comment: But if I simplify the `Series[ArcTan[x] /. {x -> (1 - cc[t])*Sqrt[k/aa[t]]}, {t, 0, 3}]` and also 
 `Simplify[Series[
   ArcTan[y] /. {y -> (cc[t])*Sqrt[k/aa[t]]}, {t, 0, 3}]] `                                          I still get strange result for                                                       `oneTwo[t_] = 
 Simplify[Series[
   ArcTan[(x + y)/(1 + x*y)] /. {x -> (1 - cc[t])*
       Sqrt[k/aa[t]]}, {y -> (cc[t])*Sqrt[k/aa[t]]}, {t, 0, 3}]]`

Comment: How can I plug in numbers? Also if two functions are equal, their `Series` are expected to be equal as well.